# JS - Compressing increases request size

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, axios, request, compression

I'm trying to compress my request but it only seems to be increasing the size of the request:

```
    const requestData = LZString.compress(
      JSON.stringify({ data: bigBase64StringHere })
    );

    await axios.post("api-endpoint", requestData, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" },
    });
```

When I console.log the original string and compressed one - the compressed one is bigger (original 400K vs compressed 500K). When I log the calculated size of them - the compressed one is half of the original (original 800K vs compressed 330K).

**Logging using `console.log`:**

*Uncompressed size:*

[image: Uncompressed size]

*Compressed size:*

[image: Compressed size]

**Logging using [sizeof](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sizeof):**

[image]

(top uncompressed, bottom compressed)

Which gives me the result the compression claims to achieve:

[pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/demo.html](https://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/demo.html)

Might it be that the compression is actually working but the Content-Length header is a bad indicator for the request size?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that a "compressed" entity can potentially be bigger than the original. This is due to the fact that additional data (compression tables and other metadata) must be added, and will depend on the source and the compression algorithm. In your case, I would compare the resulting strings sizes and use the smaller one, setting compression headers accordingly.

If the type of data that you are compressing does not give you good compression ratios consistently, then it may be simply not worth it. At last, try changing compression algorithm.

Comment: Based on the demo: https://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/demo.html, the size of the string is half of the original. Can it be that the format I'm using to send the data is wrong?

Comment: @K41F4r what is the type of your raw data and how are you converting it into a Base64 string? Are you comparing the size of the raw data with the compressed result or the size of the Base64 string with the resulting compressed string?

Comment: The base64 string is a file so I'm comparing the base64 string with the resulting compressed (string?)

Comment: Might it be that the compression is actually working but the Content-Length header is a bad indicator for the size? When I console.log the original string and compressed one - the compressed one is bigger. When I log the calculated size of them - the compressed one is half of the original.

Comment: @K41F4r if you read from line 70 of [this file](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/adapters/http.js#L45), you will find that strings are converted into a buffer using `Buffer.from()` and then size for `Content-Length` comes from `buffer.length`. Remember that it is in Bytes. So it should not be the problem. How are you measuring payload size?

Comment: I feel like I'm making some basic mistake here. I've updated the question with the size logs, really appreciate the help